# github switching accounts 'remote: Repository does not exist'

Tags: git, github, git-push, account, git-pull

I have a private github remote repo for my organization.

I had full access to it under the github account `aaaa` and had been using it.

Recently, I had to switch my github account so I removed `aaaa` from the list of users on the remote repo and added my new account `bbbb`.

Now when I locally try to `git pull` or anything else with the remote, I get the error

`remote: Repository not found.`
`fatal: repository xxxxurl not found`

I looked at github documentation and I think it is happening because locally I'm still identified as `aaaa` when I try to connect to the remote repo. Is there any way to make the remote repo think that I am `bbbb`, my new account, whenever I try to push/pull to the remote from local?

FYI I registered by ssh public key for the account but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was solved by changing the url of the remote repo.

before it was just

http://github.com/organizationname/repo.git

i changed it to

git@github.com:organizationname/repo.git

using the command

`git remote set-url remotename newurl`(above)